# Rails 4 delegate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delegates

I am really struggling with the delegate concept and how to put it into practice.

I have a Contract model which has the following fields:
company_id,
contract_type (Standard, Unlimited, Guaranteed etc etc),
fixed_cost,
cost_per_hour,
included_time,
time_credit,

there is an Invoice model which belongs to Contract and has the following fields:
contract_id,
startdate,
enddate,
total_time_used,
start_credit,
end_credit,
total_cost

I want to run a service object to create an Invoice instance, populate the total_time_used(from another table), start_credit (from the Contract table) and then calculate the total_cost.  This is calculated using data from the Contract table and the methodology is different depending on the contract_type in the Contract model e.g. Standard, Unlimited.

I don't want a big if statement in the service object as there may end up being multiple types of contract.  I see that I can have Standard, Unlimited classes with the same named method but different functionality e.g. calculate_cost but I can't quite see how to actually do it such that this method also uses data retrieved from the Contract table.

Does that make sense - probably not but if it does any guidance will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Your service object class should look like:

```
class Service
  attr_reader :contract

  delegate :method1, :method2, to: :contract

  def initialize(contract)
    @contract = contract
  end
end
```

Then you can call method1 and method2 directly inside Service

Comment: thank you for replying so quickly.. I missed off that I need to pass total_time_used from Invoice back to the calculate_cost method.  e.g. for a Standard contract total cost = fixed_cost + (total_time_used - (included_time+time_credit))*cost_per_hour

Comment: you can pass it back as an argument to delegated method calculate_cost: calculate_cost(total_time_used)

Answer (score 0):

Delegate? You mean inheritance? It seems like your problem is calculating total cost, based on the type of contract. This is typically solved using inheritance on `Contract`. e.g. define a `StandardContract` and `UnlimitedContract` which both derive from `Contract`. Problem here is: when using ActiveRecord models you will have to switch to [single table inheritance (STI)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).

An alternative is just extracting the calculation. So in `lib/contract_calculator.rb` you write

```
class ContractCalculator

  def initialize(contract)
    @contract = contract
  end 

  def total_cost(invoice)
    # default implementation or empty?
  end
end
```

and then you can add your sub-classes. In `lib\standard_contract_calculator.rb`

```
class StandardContractCalculator < ContractCalculator
  def total_cost(invoice)
    # do the calculation for a standard-contract
  end 
end
```

In `lib\unlimited_contract_calculator.rb`

```
class UnlimitedContractCalculator < ContractCalculator
  def total_cost(invoice)
    # do the calculation for a standard-contract
  end 
end
```

Now you can add the following code to `Contract`

```
def calculator
  @calculator = if contract_type == 'Standard' 
                  StandardContractCalculator.new(self)
                elsif contract_type == 'Unlimited'
                  UnlimitedContractCalculator.new(self)
                else
                  ContractCalculator.new(self)
                end
end

def total_cost(invoice)
  calculator.total_cost(invoice)
end
```

I made some shortcuts, like I have no idea how you decide what type of contract it is. So that "factory" code (creating the correct calculator based on the contract) you will definitely have to adapt. I assumed `invoice` to be a parameter, for simplicity. You could also hand it down in the constructor?

Hopefully this will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: thank you - will see how I get on with this...and let you know.